# RDP from RPi to Windows 10 (Safe Room)

Tags: raspbian, remote, windows, desktop, rdp

I'm trying to have 3 RPi connect to a Windows machine via RDP. The thing is I need the Raspberries to have a automatic boot to that machine, and, once inside, they can't leave (or if they do, it connects them again). The RPi is going to serve as a sort of "portal" to the environment the people are going to be working in.

Is there a way for me to do that?

Any more information you guys need, just ask.

PS.: I've tried Remmina, but it's to easy to leave the RDP environment.

Thanks.

Comment: what does this mean? .. `they can't leave`

Comment: they can`t leave the RDP connection to the RPi environment.

Comment: @hyped, If I understand (I'm not sure) you can write a `systemd unit file` and a bash script who would handle the connection as you want. This script must act as RDP client : connect to the server and use a loop for check the connection status, if no RDP connection , try to reconnect. [for detecting connection you can take a look on this link](https://gist.github.com/OllieJones/27592fb5660a446dccff092a0c029d11) .

Comment: What does it mean "*booting to a machine*"? What machine? A computer boots to its operating system. What should happen when the RasPi has boot up? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo I didn't write it well. It's not boot to a machine, but after booting to rhe Raspbian Buster, it connects via RDP to a Windows machine automaticaly.

Comment: Thanks to everyone that answered, but I've already found a solution. I used systemd to start a service called remote.service at boot, and configured that file to if it closes or exits it starts again.

Comment: Please make your solution an answer and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer will finish the question. Otherwise it will pop up again months for months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone that answered, but I've already found a solution. I used *rdektop* and *systemd* . I created a service called remote.service and configured that file to if it closes or exits it starts again.

Install *rdesktop* and then create a service like so:

```
sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/remote.service

     [Unit]
     Description=Remote Desktop

     [Service]
     Environment=DISPLAY=:0
     Environment=XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority
     ExecStart=/usr/bin/rdesktop -d [DOMAIN] -k [KEYBOARD] -n [RPi USER] -f [ADDRESS]
     Restart=Always
     RestartSec=[TIME IT TAKES TO RESTART APPLICATION]
     KillMode=process
     TemooutSec=infinity

     [Install]
     WantedBy=graphical.target

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable remote.service
```